# Background image property only working on firefox browser

Tags: css, wordpress

I have installed a premium theme on my WordPress website. New domain and hosting and a premium theme installed there.

Website: `https://markvillewellness.com/`

But whenever I installed the demo I noticed that the **background images** not working, same with **background video**. I contacted theme support they said server/ssl issue. Inspecting the image I saw the URL of the background image is `http://`
Then I manually added a background image(https) using **CSS** still not worked.

But I visit the website using firefox and working fine. Then I checked the website using Microsoft Edge, still not worked.

I don't know why this hepping. Can you please help me about this fixing?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your image links and ensure they are referencing https:// rather than http://

Otherwise, cache refresh Microsoft Edge and see if it was simply caching your old image

Comment: The theme is build with wp bakery page builder. I changed image on that section. The images still has http:// but if I use image on another section the image load with https://. Thanks for your reply, I am unable to check now. Because I am outside now, I will check when I return to work.